# Android cursoradapter filter listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to filter my listview with cursoradapter. This is what I've tried so far:

```
CustomAdapter adapter;
Cursor cursor;

etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher (){

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());

        }

    });

cursor = dbHelper.getAllItemInventoryListings();

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, cursor);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            String strItemCode = constraint.toString();
            return dbHelper.getAllItemInventoryListings(strItemCode);

        }
    });
```

When I tried it does not filter. What seems to be wrong? Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());`